# How to get BSSID of Access Point from client?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, access-point, bssid

I am developing a Django application and I need to know to which **access point** the client/user is connected to.

By searching in the internet I found out that I can find it using the **BSSID** of the access point.

The problem is I am **unable** to find a way to get that BSSID.

So, I want to know is there any information in the **request** object of Django.

If not, is there any other way to get the BSSID using **JavaScript**.

(Note: Please share any way that can be helpful to me).

If all those can't work can we **set some configurations** in the access point and use them to find the client access point (Yes, I have the option to set them as we are developing this application to be run on a organization server).

Any information will be **appreciated**.

***Thank you in advance***.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript itself does not allow for this (at least if ran in a browser env). It could still be possible if you fully control the user's device, but you'd have to run a workaround for that. I.e. you could store the time of connection and IP and have the workaround application monitor for connections to your site. Then you could have them store the connection and IP too, to allow you to compare these.

Tl;dr: not possible in a browser env.

Edit: It may actually be possible via a concept from the hacking community. See [this Question's top answer on the SE's Security forum](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93477/can-a-website-detect-my-local-wifi-network-i-am-in)

Comment: Thank you for the information. Highly appreciated.

Comment: No problem mate, glad I could provide you with some info. I hope the security page of stackexchange has something that can help you. Good luck!